# system.notsupportedexception the given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, chat, notsupportedexception

In my chat program I need to send file to other users but I have problem. 
When I trying to send my file visual studio give me an exception  the given path's format is not supported;

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream = null;

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "A:\\";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer).ToString();

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error:"+ ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: `openFileDialog1.ToString()` is not going to return the path of the selected file - it's going to return `System.Windows.Forms.OpenDialog` (the type of the of the object).  You want `openDialog1.FileName`.

Comment: It thrown exception after it get a pathfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);`.

You're using `openFileDialog1.ToString()`, which will return something like "System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog", not the path of the selected file.

Comment: am i suppose to store the value of opendialog1 in string variable?

Comment: What value?  `openDialog1` is an *instance* of the `OpenFileDialog` class - it has several different values (properties).

Comment: I'm going to find the pathfile to convert it into byte array. But i don't know how you get this pathfile.

Comment: @АндрійПриймак search your code for the code I mention at "You're using", and replace it with the code I suggest at "Try".